# "They told me to come tomorrow?"

Tags: grammar, tense, spoken-english, writing

I'd like you to help me with this simple question. I want to know if the question is correct, I do also would like to know what tense is used in it.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct'? Without the question mark, _They told me to come tomorrow_ is a simple statement, in the past tense. I can't imagine in what circumstances anyone would say it as a question.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you suspect may be incorrect in the sentence? If you have done some reading and are confused, that informaton would also help.

Comment: If you're confused by the use of the past tense, when "tomorrow" is included, it is because you may have been *told yesterday* to come in two days.